# What is the meaning of n-1 inside of factorial?

Tags: java

I'm new in programming and having a hard time to understand the meaning of n-1 in this program. Please help me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Samp {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int n = 5, fact;
            fact = factorial(n);
            System.out.println(fact);       
            
                
        }
        static int factorial(int n){
            if(n==0){
                return 1;
            }else{
                return (n * factorial(n-1));
            }
        }
       }
```

Comment: If you read the definition for what a factorial is, you'll find your answer in the definition itself.

Comment: `n-1` means *subtract `1` from `n`*, or what exactly don't you understand?

Comment: So without using any loops the program itself is already looping?

Comment: @Raven have a look at [Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

Answer (score 3):

In the function factorial there is a recursive call to the same function. With recursion you always need a recursion step and an anchor. In your case, the chain of recursive calls ends with `n==0`, that is the anchor. As long as `n > 0`, the recursion step (call to same function but with other parameters) multiplies the current n with the faculty of `n-1`. For example:

```
factorial(3)
3 * factorial(2)
3 * (2 * factorial(1))
3 * (2 * (1 * factorial(0)))
3 * (2 * (1 * 1))
3 * (2 * 1)
3 * 2
6
```

Comment: I see, now i understand already! Thank you so much!